# Changing data in column based on condition then making new dataframe with those changes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I make a mofication to my dataframe, setting values in `Type 1` column to be "Rocky" where `Type 1` is equal to "Rock".

```
df.loc[df['Type 1'] == 'Rock', 'Type 1'] = 'Rocky'
```

If I call df everything works as planned. The values in the `Type 1` column that were once "Rock" are now "Rocky".

This may be a rudimentary question, I'm new to Pandas. What if I didn't want those changes to take place in `df` but instead I wanted the changes to take place in a new dataframe called something else (like `df2`). Whenever I call `df` those values in the `Type 1` column should still say "Rock". Whenever I call `df2`, those values should say "Rocky." How would I create df2 and make changes to it, but leave df unchanged?

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: use `df2 = df.copy()` and then perform the same code on df2 ;)

Comment: `df1=df.copy(deep=True)`

Comment: That did it. Thank you. I was missing the .copy()